# PL/SQL anonymous block completed with no result displayed

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When I execute the procedure nth would appear except the following message and not showing any output which should not be the case: anonymous block completed

I've tried to `set serveroutput on size 50000` but nothing changes.

Here's my PL/SQL procedure not sure if i'm doing it right.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE verify AS
  empnum  NUMBER;
  empname VARCHAR2(50);
  fail EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

  SELECT employee.e#, employee.name INTO empnum, empname
    FROM employee
    JOIN driver ON driver.e# = employee.e#
    JOIN mechanic ON mechanic.e# = driver.e#
   WHERE rownum = 1;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('ok');
    RAISE fail;
END verify;
/
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result in using sql statement:

```
  SELECT employee.e#, employee.name
    FROM employee
    JOIN driver ON driver.e# = employee.e#
    JOIN mechanic ON mechanic.e# = driver.e#
   WHERE rownum = 1;
```

So if there's any similar records it will show the employee name and num. If there's no similar records found it will display a `ok` message.

Comment: What output do you expect?  Assuming that there is data in all three tables and the join relationships are correct, your query will populate two local variables with an arbitrary `e#` and `name`.  You then don't do anything with those two local variables.  I'm also not sure what benefit you get from declaring the `fail` exception here.

Comment: @JustinCave hi, thank for the prompt reply.. i've updated my question on what I would like the achieve but I'm not sure if it would work..

Comment: Is the goal to display multiple rows in the result?  Or do you just want to display one arbitrary row?  The latter doesn't make a lot of sense to me but that's what your `rownum = 1` clause implies.  Are you just learning PL/SQL from a book (in which case writing data to `dbms_output` may be reasonable)?  Or are you trying to use PL/SQL in the real world (in which case depending on `dbms_output` is a mistake)?

Comment: @JustinCave i'm actually learning from a book.. I've notice that they would actually use `dbms_output`. 

if there are multiple similar records than it would display all of them. so i think i'm suppose to remove `rownum=1`?

Comment: What does "similar" mean here?  As it stands, you aren't doing anything to compare data in the tables against anything to look for a "similar" row.  Do you mean to have a predicate other than `rownum=1`?

Comment: @JustinCave what "similar" means here is that a driver cannot be a mechanic. If this is found when executing the procedure it will actually display the employee num and name else it will display a ok message. sorry that i did not phrase my question correctly.

Comment: @JustinCave hey, thanks i think i've solve this problem.. thanks alot..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.  The question is unlikely to help future visitors.


Comment: Have you tried `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`?

Answer (score 0):

add dbms_out_put.put_line(empnum||empname);
before the EXCEPTION.
try it/

Answer (score 0):

You are just selecting the column values into the variables and not displaying them. Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Empnum: '|| empnum||' Empname: '||empname);` just after the Select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please signify the FAIL variable you have used to 
    Raise Exception. We can do it without using this variable. This 
    is reference procedure.Plz try and let us know if it works. thanks

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE av_sp_test(salary_var_1 in number)
AS
name_var avrajit.name%type;
salary_var avrajit.salary%type;
fail exception;
BEGIN
SELECT name,salary into name_var,salary_var from avrajit
WHERE salary=salary_var_1;
dbms_output.put_line('name is'||' '||name_var||' '||'salary is'||' '||salary_var);
EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
dbms_output.put_line('OK');
END av_sp_test;

--------------------------------------------------

I have taken an input variable just to show diffrenet criterias.

begin
av_sp_test(1000);
end;
---------------------------------------------------
name is Sushil salary is 1000

Statement processed.

0.01 seconds
---------------------------------------------------

begin
av_sp_test(2000);
end;
---------------------------------------------------
OK

Statement processed.

0.00 seconds
```